# Pyspark UDF - performance hit on complex return type

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a PySpark UDF that returns a tuple of String, which I've encoded as a struct. Here's a toy example,

```
def my_func(x):
  return "1", x, "3"

spark.udf.register("my_func", lambda x: my_func(x), StructType([StructField("one", StringType(),
                                                                StructField("two", StringType(), 
                                                                StructField("three", StringType()])
```

which I call

```
spark.sql("select col1, my_func(col1) from sdf").show()
```

I'm seeing a 10x - 20x performance hit for returning the entire tuple compared to returning one element of the tuple, e.g.

```
spark.udf.register("my_func", lambda x: my_func(x)[1], StringType())
```

Is this a known issue, and is there a way to avoid the conversion slowdown?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I got it to work - lmk if there's a more efficient way. To solve the performance problem,

```
1) Transform the DataFrame to an RDD[Row]

2) Apply the function to transform into a Row of the final output

3) Convert back to a DataFrame
```

Code:

```
def map_to_new_row(row):
  NewRow = Row("one", "two", "three")
  return NewRow("1", row.col1, "3")

rdd1 = df1.rdd.map(map_to_new_row)
df2 = spark.createDataFrame(rdd1, StructType([StructField("one", StringType(), 
                                              StructField("two", StringType(), 
                                              StructField("three", StringType()]))
```

This is gives me much better performance.